# ODBC string connect to specific table

Tags: sql-server, datatable, odbc, ogr2ogr

I'm connecting to a SQL Server spatial database by using ogr2ogr with the MSSQL driver.

```
C:\>ogr2ogr -f "GeoJSON" C:\Users\usr_m\Documents\shape_odbc.geojson "MSSQL:Driver=SQL Server;server=hksql;database=ql51pd;trusted_Connection=yes;"
```

as specified [here](https://alastaira.wordpress.com/ogr2ogr-patterns-for-sql-server/) and [here](https://gdal.org/drivers/vector/mssqlspatial.html)

But I'd like to connect to download a certain table, any suggestions how I do that?

Maybe I need to fetch it in python or make another workaround.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested on a side-note [here](http://osgeo-org.1560.x6.nabble.com/ogr2ogr-and-PostGIS-2-0-td5041735.html). The string has to look like this:

```
C:\>ogr2ogr -f "GeoJSON" C:\Users\usr_m\Documents\shape_odbc.geojson "MSSQL:Driver=SQL Server;server=hksql;database=ql51pd;trusted_Connection=yes;" **<table>**
```